# compare two arrays in php and out put result

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP compare array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901815/php-compare-array)

I have to compare two arrays in php and print the out put if the both arrays are same but can order elements in any way

ie

```
$array1=array('a','p','p','l','e');
$array2=array('p','a','e','l');

--- This must return as success because all of the letters in array1 is there in array2

$array1=array('a','p','p','l','e','s');
$array2=array('p','a','e','l');

-- This must return false

$array1=array('a','p','p','l','e','s');
$array1=array('a','p','p','l','e','s');
-- This must return true
```

Please help

Comment: How about using search?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901815/php-compare-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var_dump(sizeof(array_diff($array1, $array2)) === 0);
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

```
function compareArrays($array1, $array2) {
    foreach ($array2 as $currentValue) {
        if (!in_array($currentValue, $array1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```