# Comparing arrays with identical values

Tags: php, arrays, duplicate-data

```
$array1 = array(1,1,1);  
$array2= array(1,5,9,2,2,1);
```

I need to compare `$array2` with `$array1` and if `$array2` has the same identical values should return `true`, otherwise should be returning false. In this case it should return `false`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901831/1415724 (After Googling "compare arrays php") ;-)

Comment: So why don't you google on comparing arrays in php ... I bet 49Cents, you'll find your answer within 20 seconds...

Comment: @djot Actually `About 1,040,000 results (0.22 seconds)` ;-)

Comment: @Fred -ii- But I unfortunately do not get 0.49Euro(!) for each ;) of them

Comment: @djot LMAO! yeah and if I had a nickel for every time an OP doesn't bother Googling, I'd be a stockholder with Google ;-)

Comment: you are all so intelligent you find several results to compare arrays but not repeated array since if it finds a value, in_array turns true.. btw to use that method i need to use the same keys @Fred-ii- so clever

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP compare array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901815/php-compare-array)

Comment: @larrylampco how about no, has nothing to do with it.. and i wrote the solution for this and post under there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thanks @Shadowfax for trying help but i made the solution, so i post here if anyone have the same problem..

```
function compareArrayValues($array1,$array2){
$result= array();
for ($a=0; $a< count($array1); $a++){
    $array2=array_values($array2);
    for ($b=0; $b < count($array2) ; $b++) { 
        if ($array1[$a] == $array2[$b]){
            array_push($result,$array1[$a]);
            unset($array2[$b]);
            break;
        }
    }

}
if ($result == $array1){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `==` and `===` operators.

`$array1 == $array2` only checks if the two arrays contain the same key/value pairs and `$array1 === $array2` also checks if they are in the same order and if they are of the same type.

See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

Comment: yes i know this method but i can't use the same keys

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $array1 == $array2 ) {
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

Note: keys must be same too.

---

To check only values:

```
if(!array_diff($array1, $array2) && !array_diff($array2, $array1)) 
   return true;
```

Comment: SO would have moved such an answer given by me to comments ... as too trivial ;)

Comment: yes i know this method but i can't use the same keys

Comment: By saying `Well, doesn't work.`- will not help you. What error you are getting?

Comment: because `array_diff` checks only one value, i have `$array1 = array(1,1,1);  
$array2= array(1,5,9,2,2,1);` should be false because i don't have three 1 on `$array2 `

Comment: Can reduce that to `return ($array1 == $array2);`