# How to check if two arrays contain the same values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I have to compare them against each other:

```
$a = array('BRANCH','ADDRESS','MOBILE','NAME');
$b = array('BRANCH','ADDRESS','MOBILE','NAME');

$a == $b → true
```

But when the values are in a different order, this comparison doesn't work:

```
$a = array('BRANCH','ADDRESS','MOBILE','NAME');
$b = array('NAME','BRANCH','MOBILE','ADDRESS');

$a == $b → false
```

How do i compare these two arrays to see if both contain the same values, regardless of their order?

Comment: sort arrays before comparing

Comment: `array_diff` approach should solve your issue

Comment: your question is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901815/php-compare-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) which check difference between two arrays.

```
$areEqual = array_diff($a, $b) === array_diff($b, $a);
```

or

```
$areEqual = !(array_diff($a, $b) || array_diff($b, $a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort($a);
sort($b);
if ($a==$b) {
echo "arraysAreEqual";
}
```

Comment: Valid approach, but it alters the original arrays, which may be undesirable.