# how to compare value in array php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have data in array

```
[list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 216
                [name] => item A
                [nilai] => 0.456
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 217
                [name] => item B
                [nilai] => 0.999
            )
    )
```

here I want to make a condition if the value is the largest then the text is green
how to make the condition in foreach ?

this my code

```
<?php foreach($res['method']['list'] as $key=>$row) { ?>
     <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1"><?php echo $row['nilai'] ?></label>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP compare array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901815/php-compare-array)

Comment: there are two approaches, sort it and print the first element of the array with the green color, OR loop over it and get the max value in in the other loop check if the value is equal to the max value then make it green

Comment: give me an example

Comment: There are good examples in the given link.

I would use the solution in the given link to find the highest value and then use that in you're for loop.

Comment: [Find highest value in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339421/find-highest-value-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Your loop is creating duplicate `id` attributes within the `foreach()` which will render your html document invalid and generate an unpredictable/unwanted user experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  <?php
  $val_array = array_column($res['method']['list'], 'nilai');
  $hightestValueIndex = array_keys($val_array, max($val_array));
  foreach($res['method']['list'] as $key=>$row) { ?>
      <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
  <?php if ($key == $hightestValueIndex[0]){ ?>
          <label style="color:green;" class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1"><?php echo $row['nilai'] ?></label>
  <?php} else { ?>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1"><?php echo $row['nilai'] ?></label>
      </div>
  <?php } } ?>
```

In the above code we at first extract the 'nilai' in separate and find max value and store it's index using that index in foreach loop we can achieve the desired result

Comment: It makes better sense to check `in_array($key, $hightestValueIndex)` in case multiple rows contain the max value.  Only the `style="color:green;"` should be conditionally written; not the entire `<label>` markup.

Answer (score 0):

This will first calculate the maximum 'nilai' value in your list, and then in array_map a copy of your list will be created with an additional key 'max' for each item in your list. This value will be set to 'true' or 'false' depending on nihai being equal to $maxNilai or not. You then can use that 'max' boolean value to color in green or not.

```
$list = [
    [ 'id' => 216, 'name' => 'item A', 'nilai' => 0.456 ],
    [ 'id' => 217, 'name' => 'item B', 'nilai' => 0.999 ]
];

$maxNilai = max(array_column($list, 'nilai'));

$result = array_map(
    fn($item) => array_merge($item, [ 'max' => $item['nilai'] === $maxNilai ]),
    $list
);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 216
            [name] => item A
            [nilai] => 0.456
            [max] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 217
            [name] => item B
            [nilai] => 0.999
            [max] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: helo @lucas.j I use this function but error , the message :

syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP version 7.1

Comment: Then you have to replace the line starting with _fn($item) => ..._ with this code: _function ($item) use ($maxNilai) {
      return array_merge($item, [ 'max' => $item['nilai'] === $maxNilai ]);
    },:_

Comment: It is the same code, but written as a function instead of the arrow function version. Arrow functions are available since PHP 7.4 (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php).

Comment: $result = array_map(
     function ($item) use ($maxNilai ) { 
      return array_merge($item, [ 'max' => $item[' nilai'] === $maxNilai ]); 
     }
    );

I'm like trying this but it still fails

Comment: Yes, because you deleted the line _$list_. The code I gave you only replaces the line starting with _fn($item) => ... _

Comment: _array_map_ has two arguments, the function, and the list.

Comment: can you write the full code? thanks